# Find location of document in Mongodb cluster,

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I had to store a million documents into Mongodb. Mongodb cluster consists of 4 shards,1 mongos and 1 config server.

How to get details of document like:

1. Which shard contains document?
2. Which chunk contains document?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hey to find location of document you can use [expalain()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/)

**Steps to find location of document**

```
1. Open Mongos terminanl

2. Switch to your databse

3. find document of which you want to search location using explain()

eg db.collection.find({"x":1234}).explain()
```

You will get result in json format, look for **shards** key into it. More details check [link](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/explain-results/#explain.executionStats)